# How to drop rows in python that don't have date values?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I need help cleaning a very large dataframe. One of the rows is "PostingTimeUtc" should be only dates but several rows inserted wrong and they have strings of text instead. How can I select all the rows for "PostingTimeUtc" which have strings instead of dates and drop them?

I'm new to this site and to coding, so please let me know if I'm being vague.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Please remember to add examples even if short -

This may work in your case:

```
from pandas.api.types import is_datetime64_any_dtype as is_datetime

df[df['column name'].map(is_datetime)]
```

Where `map` applies the `is_datetime` function (results in `True` or `False`) to each row and the Boolean filter is applied to the dataframe.

Don't forget to assign `df` to this result to retain the values as it is not done `inplace`.

```
df = df[df['column name'].map(is_datetime)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming it's the pandas data frame. You can do this to filter rows on the basis of regex.

```
df.column_name.str.contains('your regex here')
```